# Can't run queries in database console from php

Tags: phpstorm

I've just readl the Database Code Completion while working in PHP on your web support. So I've configured the database, I can complete the queries with ctrl+enter but I can't run query on console. I send you some pictures to explain the problem. 
I've the database configured, so I can check the tables and all the dates, and run queries directly at the console, but can't send from php the query.

Thanks for all, Manu.

[image: What Should be]

[image: My problem on alt+enter]

Comment: very few information for helping you. Please talk about your code (framework, concept, bundle, etc...) and share it.

Comment: Solved, the problem solved when I tryied the same process with a local file, so the problem was work directly on remote files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect to the DB before you run any queries on it (example in MySQL here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp, don't forget to close it when you don't need it anymore. )

The result is not plain text, you need to go through it in a loop (example including the connection here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp ).

Comment: I think you are in a incorrect way, dto you know phpstorm well ?

Comment: I don't know anything about phpstorm, but I've been working with php and MySQL some time ago. The commands in your question just set a php variable value to a string (which contains a query, but nothing is done with it in the code that you posted).

Comment: Yes, I know, but this is not the nature of the problem, but thanks !